# How to use wrapper div & using flexbox on sections

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building my first website, and I am having some issues figuring out how to combine a wrapper that limits the `max-width` of the content and using flexbox on a section.

A typical section of my website would look like:

```
<section class="hero flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <p>Content 2</p>
    <button>Content 3</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am running into the following problems:

1. When adding the wrapper `div` between `section` & the content, the content is no longer direct children of `section`, and thus are not affected by the flexbox. Therefore I cannot center the content.
2. If I put the classes `.hero` and `.wrapper` on the `section` tag, the background color is affected by the `width/max-width` of wrapper

I'm sure that I'm running into more problems that I still haven't found yet. I am therefore interested in how to use a wrapper for limited max-width together with flexbox sections.

Comment: Missing a closing brackets after your div's class 'wrapper'.

Comment: _"When adding the wrapper div between section & the content, the content is no longer direct children of section, and thus are not affected by the flexbox."_ - then put the `flex` class on the wrapper element, instead of the section?

Comment: @CBroe But then, I would have to put all other formatting for the section (e.g. `justify-content`, `align-items`, etc.) in `.flex`or `.wrapper`in the CSS file. Since the code will differ from section to section, this is not optimal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the entire problem, including why you can't use the more obvious solutions.

Comment: Why, you can apply style based on selectors like `section.foo > .wrapper`, if you want to format stuff inside a section with class `foo` differently.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What do you mean "show the entire problem"? Also, please tell me what the more obvious solutions would be? Nothing is obvious for a beginner :)

Comment: Well, you added conditions based on @CBroe's comment, so we need to know any requirements which exist. Obvious meaning, if you add an element between a section and content, it adds an element between the section and the content. The obvious solution is to move or copy the styles from the section to the new element.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.hero{
  max-width: 700px;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section ="hero flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <p>Content 2</p>
    <button>Content 3</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: At the moment, my wrapper class looks like this:

`.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}`

Maybe this is not the best way to make it?

Comment: If you want to make sure everything displays properly on smartphones, tablets and large screens (as well as other devices/browsers setups), you should probably consider using @media queries to improve the display on these various devices. This is a good introduction to responsive design: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Answers which explain what code is doing and why are more often upvoted than downvoted.